# Как c помощью c++ можно узнать серийный номер жесткого диска?

Tags: c++, linux, железо, hdd

Как узнать серийный номер жесткого диска в ОС Линукс?
Да и вообще, как на с++ работать с аппаратным обеспечением компьютера?

Answer (score 6):

1. > Как узнать серийный номер жесткого диска в ОС Линукс?

   В зависимости от того, какой у вас дистрибутив и что в нем есть. Можно использовать разные сторонние утилиты GNU:

   `hdparm -I /dev/sd? | grep 'Serial\ Number'`

   `lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial`

   `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL`

   `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/`
2. > Да и вообще, как на с++ работать с аппаратным обеспечением компьютера?

   [ioctl()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049895)