# python как узнать серийный номер жесткого диска linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

как с помощью python узнать серийный номер жесткого диска в linux

linux версии 4.14.116

Comment: Я бы предложил: выполнить из пайтона команду, котрая может это сказать. А саму команду - можно узнать из вопроса, который уже задавался: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488201/

Comment: @S.H. можно и без команд. непосредственно обратиться к программе linux — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/823644/178576 — прочитать информацию прямо из файлов псевдо-фс `/sys`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

за информацией [можно обратиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/823644/178576) непосредственно к программе *linux*. точнее, к файлам виртуальной файловой системы [`sysfs`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), обычно примонтированной в каталог `/sys`.

на языке программирования *python* это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob

for wwid in glob.glob("/sys/block/*/device/wwid"):
    print(wwid)
    with open(wwid, "r") as file:
        try:
            data = file.readline().strip()
            print(data)
        except:
            print("not readable")
```

пример результата выполнения:

```
/sys/block/sdd/device/wwid
t10.ATA     Hitachi HDS721010CLA332                       JP2940HD33Z1JC
/sys/block/sdb/device/wwid
t10.ATA     ST2000VX008-2E3164                                  Z52AV6HP
/sys/block/sde/device/wwid
not readable
/sys/block/sdc/device/wwid
t10.ATA     Hitachi HDS721010CLA332                       JP2940HD33YXGC
/sys/block/sda/device/wwid
t10.ATA     ST2000VX008-2E3164                                  Z52AKGD1
```